# How to get URL value from html with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I found a problem with my homework on how to get the URL value from html using php. I tried a website to try my code, but i need get some URL with pattern (specific result)
example : *https: //video.xxxxxxx/*

my code :

```
$regexp = "/<a\s[^>]*href=([\"\']??)([^\\1 >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU";
  if(preg_match_all("$regexp", $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach($matches as $match) {
      echo $match[0];
    }
  }
```

Comment: please be more specific, as it is currently written, your post may never have any answer

Comment: Please include some sample inputs and their desired outputs along with the question.

Comment: @Pierre I've edited my answer multiple times in a few minutes, so please refer to its most recent version, which is the one right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<a.*?href\s*=\s*([\"\'])(.*?)\1.*?>.*?<\/a>
```

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/SSZU4v/2)**

I've never used PHP before, so you might have to use `\\1` instead of `\1`

## Explanation:

It's tedious to explain every single element of this, so I'll give you a general idea. First you match the `a` tag, followed by *any number of characters, styles, or different attributes*, then followed by `href=`. Here, we start the capturing group 1, which contains your `'` or `"`. Capturing group 2 contains your website's url without the quotations. Then we use `\1` to refer to the type of quotation first used.

If you want the text within the `a` tag, for whatever reason, you can refer to it using `\3`

**Do note:** You'll need to use `match[2]` instead of `match[0]`